# Excel - use Power Query to separate one column into several columns based on another column

Tags: powerquery

Let's say I have a table like this:

```
Var1 Group
1    A
2    B
3    A
4    B
5    A
```

I wish to have a table like this:

```
A B
1 2
3 4
5
```

How can I achieve this specifically using Power Query in Excel?

Answer (score 0):

Try below

Right-click Group column and do Group By ...

Use the default option then change code in the formula box to resemble the below, especially after the **each**

```
= Table.Group(Source, {"Group"}, {{"xx", each Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Index", 1, 1), type table}})
```

click on arrows atop the new column and [x] expand Var1 and Index

Click on Group column, Transform ... pivot columns .. and choose Var1 as Values Column

Erase extra index column

Full sample code:

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Group"}, {{"xx", each Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Index", 1, 1), type table}}),
#"Expanded xx" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "xx", {"Var1", "Index2"}, {"Var1", "Index"}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Expanded xx", List.Distinct(#"Expanded xx"[Group]), "Group", "Var1", List.Sum),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{"Index2"})
in  #"Removed Columns"
```